# CloudFlare blocks download from JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup, cloudflare

I'm trying to download file with Jsoup library from a website with CloudFlare protection.

When I do this in my browser - the file downloads.

But when I download it with Java (Jsoup) - CloudFlare sends me a page "Checking your browser before accessing" and file can't be downloaded. I tried to include all cookies and headers that my browser sends to the website but it doesn't help.

Is it possible to bypass this protection?

Comment: Cloudflare protection requires javascript to run. The cookies expire after X amount of time (Whenever you pass their protection). If you want to do it properly I would suggest writing your own bypass for their JS challenge, sometimes even recaptcha ( It is displayed upon bad IP Score, big amount of requests). You can also look at other public sources such as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453491/how-to-bypass-cloudflare-ddos-or-redirect-after-5-seconds-using-jsoup . Another option would be proxifying the request via a SOCK/HTTP proxy which does not have "bad ip score".

Comment: I tried to buy different VDS (Virtual Dedicated Server) on different sites and the result was the same: CloudFlare sends me JS Cchallenge. So, I think that I need to bypass JS challenge programmatically.